# Secure Bearer token in Authorization header in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, token, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

Within my Laravel 9 (Jetstream) installation, I've createad an account (admin) and also created an API token for it directly from the user interface available by default. So the API has an account and an API token for it.

I am able to login to my (Laravel) API, using that token as a `Bearer token` method 'Authorization: Bearer '.

Everything fine for now, I can access protected routes of the API that are only available for logged-in users.

I've implemented this approach within my frontend app (SPA), **which is on a different domain**.

[image]

At a certain point in my frontend app, I need to communicate with my API, so I am doing a request to it using the same approach like I did in Postman. Basically, within my (axios) request, I am configuring the route to the api, and also the required header (Authorization: Bearer xxxx) to authorize the request using the Bearer token.

```
axios.post(
    'url', 
    {
        "body": data
    }, 
    {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer <my token>'
        }
    }
 )
```

**Now, my main problem is that this request (including the token) can be seen in Chrome Developer tools for example (or other request trackings tools)**

[image]

How can I secure this in a easy and strong way?

For those who know more about Laravel, this way of authorization that comes from Jetrstream is Sanctum, and comes out of the box. I know there's another method of creating tokens, by making an initial request to the API using basic auth, and in response, I'll get a token that I should use for each request. But does that mean that it's more secure? In the end, that "fresh" token will be also visible to next requests, right? Even if it will be deleted on logout. If someone sees that token, he can easily make a request to my API using it and pretend to be a logged in user.

Is JWT a solution?

There must be something that I'm missing here. Any solutions are welcome

Comment: The Sanctum token is created for a given user, so only the "logged in" user can see its own token. What is the issue with this? Your User model should extends `authenticable` and implements `hasApiTokens` trait.

Comment: Attaching the bearer token to the request header is common when interfacing between the client and server which is why they almost always have an expiration time. The token is only valid for as long as you allow it to be. I'm assuming you add additional policies and gates to the requested data server-side?

Comment: Sanctum will only use the bearer token if you authenticate third party apps, that don't run on your domain or subdomain.
If you have a domain, then you can authenticate without token

Comment: I've updated my question so it would be more clear. 
@Mtxz the implementation of the token is already done as you mentioned.
Super_Simon I know, this kind of token is a very longer one, but either it is valid for only few minutes, it could be enough for certain people to reach my API using that valid token and do something unauthorized.
sta Yes, I have a domain, but as I said, it's not on the same domain or subdomain as the API is, it's a different one. I know that Sanctum will use the bearer token for 3rd pary apps, but if you see my token, you could also use it from anywhere

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the use case. Is it a token given to a user after he login to your app? Or is it a "global" token you created, added in your code, and so everyone on your app will use this same "public" token? I don't get what the issue is: it's the same as session hijacking? If I steal your Chrome session data, I'm able to impersonate you. Same as the token.

Comment: @Mtxz I've created the token for a specific user only (an admin let's say) and I intend to use it in order to secure the comunication between my SPA and my API. Basically the API has some "protected" routes, that are available only to the logged-in users (admin in our case) and the SPA will use admin's token to access/login those protected routes from the API. Does it makes sense now?

Comment: So only the "admin" that logs in can see it's own token, and it's own only right?

Comment: Since the SPA is a public one, everybody can inspect and see the request made to my API, where the token is included. So again, my API has a single user (admin) and my SPA actually logges in to the API using the token of that "admin" to exchange some sensitive data. I want to protect that token, so it won't be able for others to see it and maybe use it in unauthorized requests. But now, if you inspect the API, you can see the token and you can use it in your own request, simulating that you're actully the SPA. Hopr it makes sense now.